# undo a unintentionally rootcategory move

Tags: admin, category

i had this category structure:

> root 1
>    - sub1
>    - sub2
>   root 2
>   root 3

now i accidentally drag and dropped "root 2" into "root 1":

> root 1
>    - sub1
>    - sub2
>    - root 2
>   root 3

How can i undo this?
Drag and drop seems not to work. I also tried to change the db fields catalog_category_entity.parent_id to 1 and catalog_category_entity.level to 1 directly. No effect (cache was rebuilt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information for the categories is stored in the database table `catalog_category_entity` and you need to update the following three column to set an item as a root category:

1. parent_id - this should be set to the id of the true root category, this true root normally have the columns `level` and `parent_id` set to 0,
2. level - this should be set to 1 which is the first visible level in the admin section, this level contains all the root categories,
3. path - this should be set to the following `true_root_id/current_category_id`

Normally I would tell you to stay away from changes being made directly in the database but in this case the admin interface will not allow you to drag a current category and make it a root category.

**Please note that change the database directly is bad and you should always work locally first and make a back-up before hand**