# How to move all my root categories and subcategories in to one single root category

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I use Magento 1.8.1 i created an online store with around 8 root categories and (8-12) sub-categories under each root category now my client wants to create a new root category namely products and move all the root categories and sub-categories in to the newly created category.

As I am new to Magento i do know whether this is achievable or will i face any drawbacks by changing the root categories and sub-categories as category ID's and URL will be affected.

If it is recommended and achievable how can i do it or should i do a fresh start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any problem. I didn't try it out, but I would just try it (on my local copy) to move all the categories into one big category. If this doesn't work, because the JS denies it to move root categories into other categories, I would write a script which just makes `$category->move()` calls.

And [undo a unintentionally rootcategory move](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/10451/217) let me assume, you can just drag and drop it.

When you use `$category->move()` make sure to delete the generated url rewrites if you wish to.